# Same mySQL Insert query ran from two different locations in the same script, producing different results when it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql

If you look at the code marked: `/*********` below you will see the same exact **insert** query appear twice in the code below. The first block of code (towards the top) inserts the row as expected, however, it is not where I need it to be and I only put it there for debugging purposes. The second block of code is where I need to run the insert query from. When I try to run the insert query from there, it inserts a blank row.

It seems as if the variables lose their values once they reach the inner most if-statement, and I cannot come up with a logical explanation as to why it is doing this.

What I tried to solve this problem:

***Added `mysql_real_escape_string` to my stored variables

***Removed AUTO_INCREMENT id field from my insert query

***Tried inserting string literals from within all the nested if-statements - which worked fine, but as soon as I changed those string-literals to the variables I need, it inserts a blank row.

***Added or die(mysql_error()) to the query, which produced no errors.

Please advice, as it is crucial that I get this working correctly...

**Note:** I never ran both insert queries in the same script, I just added the same 'insert' code blocks to my script below twice, to make it clear to the readers what I have tried to get it working, and how the script responded as a result.

```
<?php

        session_start();
        //Create mysql connect variable
        $conn = mysql_connect('myhostedresource.com', 'user', 'password');

        //kill connection if error occurs
        if(!$conn){
            die('Error: Unable to connect.' . '<br>' . mysql_error());
        }

        //connect to mysql database
        mysql_select_db("stevenash", $conn);

        // PHP 4.1
        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];       


        $usr_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']);
        $usr_compname = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['compname']);
        $usr_city = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['city']);
        $usr_state = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['state']);
        $usr_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['phone']);
        $usr_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
        $usr_first = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['first']);
        $usr_last = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['last']);


     //********************************************************                      

        $myString = "INSERT users (`email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`) 
                                    VALUES('".$usr_email."','".$usr_compname."','".$usr_city."','".$usr_state."','".$usr_phone."','".$usr_password."','".$usr_first."','".$usr_last."')";
        echo $myString;     

        mysql_query($myString,$conn);

  //********************************************************


        if (!$fp) {
            // HTTP ERROR
        }else{
            fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
                if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                    // check the payment_status is Completed
                    if($payment_status == 'Completed'){
                        $txn_id_check = mysql_query("SELECT txn_id FROM log WHERE txn_id='$txn_id'");
                        //add user to database
                        if(mysql_num_rows($txn_id_check) != 1){ //payment has not been processed yet
                            //continue processing
                            if($receiver_email=='mat9@gmail.com'){
                                if($payment_amount=='1.00' && $payment_currency=='USD'){
                                    //add transaction id to db
                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO log (`log_id`, `txn_id`, `email`) VALUES('','$txn_id','$payer_email')", $conn);    



                                 //********************************************************                      


                                    $myString = "INSERT users (`email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`) 
                                                VALUES('".$usr_email."','".$usr_compname."','".$usr_city."','".$usr_state."','".$usr_phone."','".$usr_password."','".$usr_first."','".$usr_last."')";
                                    echo $myString;     

                                    mysql_query($myString,$conn);

                                 //********************************************************
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                        // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
                        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                        // process payment
                    }
                    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                        // log for manual investigation
                    }
                }
                fclose ($fp);
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are making it through all those conditional statements to where the query is execute?

Comment: Yes, I am. The other mysql query within all those conditional statements runs correctly, and adds a row the database. Moreover, a blank row wouldn't be created if the mysql_query within all the conditional statements was never reached.

Comment: Do this: add `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` where your INSERT is, and see what variables are set. Do the var's within your query have values?

Comment: I don't see any simple explanation here. You don't want to run mysql_real_escape_string on those variables if `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` returns TRUE. And you haven't run mysql_real_escape_string on `$txn_id` or `$payer_email` before you use them in the query. Is it possible there's an INSERT TRIGGER on the "users" table?

Comment: @spencer7593 I dont run mysql_real_escape_string on $txn_id and $payer_email becasue that query inserts the row as it should. I don't think there is any problem with the 'users' table because, if you look at my code, I ran the same exact insert query outside all the nested if statements, for dubugging, and it inserts all values to the 'users' table as expected. The problem comes in when I try to run that exact query, from within all the nested if statements, then it inserts a blank row.

Comment: @sixeightzero, I tried simply echoing out all the variables within all the nested if-statements, and nothing prints out. Though I am sure the variables are infact set, becase I am able to print them out before the conditional statments, and I am able to run the query and insert those values as well (before the conditional statments).

Comment: What if your query was 'INSERT INTO users' instead of just 'INSERT users' although that still wouldnt make much sense?

Comment: 'INTO' is optional... a row wouldn't be created in the first query if 'INTO' keyword was the problem.

Comment: @MHZ, that is why I asks you to run a specific command. You need to know if they are set, null or empty. Echo tells you nothing.